# Google calendar crash on start

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I followed all steps from the google guide:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android

But when i try to run my app this one crashes directly, this is the logCat

```
07-14 16:15:57.779: D/dalvikvm(2246): Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-14 16:15:57.803: D/AndroidRuntime(2246): Shutting down VM
07-14 16:15:57.807: W/dalvikvm(2246): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6300288)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.googlecalendar/com.example.googlecalendar.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.googlecalendar.MainActivity
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.googlecalendar.MainActivity
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
07-14 16:15:57.807: E/AndroidRuntime(2246):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post a code sample

Comment: You can find all code on the link

Comment: That's a link to Google's code, not the code that you typed out or copy-pasted. From the java.lang.RuntimeException and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException I would say there is something incomplete with your configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Step 3 of [the guide you linked](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android), it says to name the application "CalendarQuickstart".  That would produce a package name of "com.example.calendarquickstart".  In the `logcat` you posted, the package name is "com.example.googlecalendar". Did you enter "googlecalendar" as the appication name, or modify the source files after you copied and pasted from the web page?

Check that the package names in your manifest, build.gradle file, and source files are the same.

I just followed the steps in the guide to create the demo project and am able to launch it without the error you reported.

Comment: Oh yes, when i do de refractor of the package name i miss bulid.gradle, im really genius thanks